# Dynamically creating a jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm having trouble creating a jQuery Accordion using javascript.  It creates the Accodion labels just fine, and shows the text of the first element too.  It does not show the second elements text, and when you click on it, you lose the first oned text forever too.

```
$("#tab-dock").append('<div id="daccordion">')

$("#daccordion").append('<div id="dinfo"><h3><a href="#">Info</a></h3>')
$("#dinfo").append('<div>Some info about this location.</div>')
$("#daccordion").append('</div>')

$("#daccordion").append('<div id="dmarket"><h3><a href="#">Market</a></h3>')
$("#dmarket").append('<div>Market info would go here!</div>')
$("#daccordion").append('</div>')

$("#tab-dock").append('</div>')

$("#daccordion").accordion({ header: "h3",navigation: true });
```

I have another Accodion which was created normally and it works fine.  I just can't get them to match up though.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Edit:  Thanks for all of the suggestions, learned quite a bit just from them.  The problem turned out to be due to size, I had to call the Accordion's resize to get it working.

Comment: You're not using append properly - it isn't meant to add a line of markup to the existing page, it's meant to append full nodes to the existing DOM. For example, $('#tab-dock').append('<div id="daccordion"></div>'); Refactor your code and see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the closing `</div>` tags in your `append` calls.  That may be part of your trouble.

I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/hkCuf/) - seems to work fine.  Maybe I don't understand the issue.  Can you clarify a bit?  Actually, the only thing that I added that wasn't in your question was the holder for the accordion.  I created a `div` like so:

```
<div id='tab-dock'></div>
```

Is this your holder markup?

Comment: Whoa, fiddle is neat.  Thanks for that!  My problem was resolved using the accordion's resize method.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `<div id="dinfo">` tag (and closing tag). An accordion has the following structure:

```
<div>
    <h3>
    <div>
    <h3>
    <div>
</div>
```

You now have an extra `div` around each accordion panel (each `h3`,`div` combination).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a combination of both these answers. First, the structure you've set up doesn't really jive with the default jQuery UI build. Second, "append" needs to be fed complete items (either in "" form or "", either works). Something like this will do what you wanted I think http://jsfiddle.net/wdy8z/2/

```
$("#tab-dock").append('<div id="daccordion" />');

$("#daccordion").append('<h3><a href="#">Info</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dinfo">Some info about this location.</div>')
    .append('<h3><a href="#">Market</a></h3>')
    .append('<div id="dmarket">Market info would go here!</div>');

$("#daccordion").accordion({ header: "h3",navigation: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions, learned quite a bit just from them.  The problem turned out to be due to size, I had to call the Accordian's resize